# Convert a javascript board array into a html tictactoe board

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im making a tictactoe game. It's not the traditional one which the board is only 3x3, but infinity in size

Im trying to convert an array of a board that looks like this:
`[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]`
into a html board. basically each "0" of the array is a tile.

```
toBoard([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
function toBoard(arr) {
  var newBoard = document.createElement("table");
  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++) {
      var tile = document.createElement('th')
      var sqr = document.createElement("img");
      sqr.src = "client/emptySquare.svg";
      sqr.id = `${a} ${b}`;
      sqr.onclick = () => tileClickHandler(sqr.id);
      tile.appendChild(sqr);
      row.appendChild(tile)
    }
    newBoard.appendChild(row)
  }
  return newBoard;
}
```

I tried to use a table, each cell of the table will have an image element (they will have a onclick function so the game knows which part of the table the player clicked) but it doesn't work.

The table looks  like this:

[image]

As you can see the board has ugly unwanted spacing. I tried to set border-spacing to 0px but it still doesn't work. How to fix this issue? Or is there a better and more efficient way than table and images?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript, you should be able to solve it entirely with CSS. The way a table is rendered is the same whether it was created using HTML or JavaScript.

Comment: You need to delcare `sqr` with `let` rather than `var`. Otherwise, it's scoped to the function, and all the `onclick` functions will use the same value of `sqr.id`.

Comment: .tableCss > * > * > td {
                border: solid yellowgreen;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .tableCss{border-collapse: collapse;} use the border collapse attribute on the table

Comment: Can we see your CSS? You could also use a CSS grid instead and just set the gap to 0.

Comment: i just checked it again. yea, this could be solved with css entirely